# SQL Server Management Studio disable "no row was updated" popup

Tags: insert, popup, ssms, data-entry

I am doing few experiment with data ingestion procedure onto a SQL Server development environmente.
For each test i copy few thousand of row inside the DB using SSMS GUI (not scrip) because it's quicker. But every time i do a mistake in sample data format, have to manually close a ton of popup of the kind "no row was updated" (one for each bad formatted row).

I wonder if there is a way to not display a popup for every error inside the test batch, it dirve me crazy the fact that i have to manually close thousand of popup or just restart SSMS process.

Comment: Just *don't* use the GUI (to edit your data). That *is* the solution. Learn to write your SQL.

Comment: @Larnu i appreciate you contribution, but the "learn to write your SQL" part is a bit unpolite and opinionanted IMHO. Clearly there are reason if i have found this approach cheaper (in term of time) and clearly i can't concisely explain here. That said my evaluation may be wrong, but don't assume ignorance only because i choose a tradeoff that seems strange

Comment: It's not unpolite or opinionated at all, @Skary . If you learn to write the SQL, which you should be doing for *many* reasons, the problem doesn't exist. The problem is because you are using the designer, rather than writing the SQL.

Comment: @Larnu, ok i don't want to start a controversy here. Just clarify that i "choose" to use gui instead of script (maybe for the wrong reason). That said maybe you are right that i have to improve my SQL knowledge, but i don't understand why there is the need to jump to a conclusion and criticizing my skill when a simple "the tool X is not suitable for that" was enoght.

Comment: I haven't criticized your skill anywhere, @Skary ... If you want to use the designer, that is your choice, but suffering those pop-ups is just one of many features you're going to have to "get used to".

Answer (score 1):

press and hold the esc key till popups are gone for all records throwing error.. It is the only easiest solution I know

Comment: Hold ESC key is a good solution when you insert a few rows (less than hundreds). I didn't know that and it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Only "solution" to reduce the pop ups in the first place would be to copy only the first row and try with it before using the whole batch of rows.

- there is not yet an option in the designer section
  [Table and Database Designer Options SSMS 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLTOh.png)
- The designer evaluates each line as its on statement with its own transaction by design. Therefore its capable of inserting individual rows that are not affected by an error. There is also no option to change this behavior at query execution section.